# no change form value in second select url in angular7

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript

I have a list of categories and I need when I click on the edit button, open the edit form and put the value of that category to edit them.

when I click for the first time its ok and work good but in second click URL change but the value of form not change and need to refresh the page for change value.

[Sample Code](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1w3e1k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts)

this is my routing code :

```
{
    path: 'categroies', component: ManagegategoriesComponent, children: [
      { path: '', component: AddcategoriesComponent },
      { path: 'edit/:id', component: EditcategoryComponent }
    ]
  }
```

this html code :

```
    <div class="CatrgoryTitle col-md-12 col-x-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 mt-1">
        <router-outlet></router-outlet>
</div>
<div class="CatrgoryTitle col-md-12 col-x-12 col-sm-12 col-lg-12 mt-4">
        <nz-table #basicTable [nzData]="listOfData" class="table table-responsive">
            <thead>
                <tr>
                    <th>نام دسته</th>
                    <th>عملیات</th>
                </tr>
            </thead>
            <tbody>
                <tr *ngFor="let item of basicTable.data">
                    <td>{{item.name}}</td>
                    <td>
                            <button class="btn btn-warning"
                                routerLink="/panel/dashboard/categroies/edit/{{item.id}}">ویرایش</button>
                    </td>
                </tr>
            </tbody>
        </nz-table>
</div>
```

**what's the problem ? how can I solve this problem??**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you must use this code in constructor :

```
private router:ActivatedRoute

 this.router.params.subscribe(routeParams => {
   /// load data
 }
```

Answer (score 0):

Might be the problem because of `routerLink`, because on first click you will redirected on edit page and when you again click then the url will not be refresh,

Try below solution for this,

Use `router.Navigate()` method for this

In .ts,

```
import { Router } from '@angular/router';

constructor(
        private router: Router
    ) { }

onRedirectToEdit(item){
   this.router.navigate(['/panel/dashboard/categroies/edit', item.id]);
}
```

In Html,

```
<td>
    <button class="btn btn-warning" (click)="onRedirectToEdit(item)">ویرایش</button>
</td>
```

in `edit.ts`

```
ngOnInit() {
     this.route.params.subscribe(params => {
      if (params && params['id']) {
        this.id = +params['id'];
      }
    });
  }
```

Comment: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-1w3e1k?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.module.ts

Comment: check the updated answer https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmfvec?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts

Comment: I have updated my answer as well, you just need to subscribe your ActivatedRoute

Answer (score 0):

As per you have given [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-jmfvec?file=src%2Fapp%2Fedit%2Fedit.component.ts).

You need to subscribe the router parameters on each change

```
this.route.paramMap.subscribe(res=> {
   this.id = res.get('id');
});
```